# Handling csv datetime parsing when hour=24 - pandas

Tags: csv, parsing, datetime, pandas

I am trying to import a timeseries from a bigger csv files, by pointing to specific columns, here extracted. The columns have no heading, so I am superimposing it with `df_time.columns = ['Year','Month','Day','Hour']`.

```
2030    1   1   1   2.4
2030    1   1   2   2.1
2030    1   1   3   1.7
2030    1   1   4   1
2030    1   1   5   0.9
2030    1   1   6   1.5
2030    1   1   7   1.1
2030    1   1   8   0.6
2030    1   1   9   1.4
2030    1   1   10  2.2
2030    1   1   11  2
2030    1   1   12  3
2030    1   1   13  2.4
2030    1   1   14  2.6
2030    1   1   15  3.1
2030    1   1   16  2.6
2030    1   1   17  1.9
2030    1   1   18  1.9
2030    1   1   19  2.6
2030    1   1   20  1.7
2030    1   1   21  1.1
2030    1   1   22  1.3
2030    1   1   23  1.4
2030    1   1   24  1.7
2030    1   2   1   2.1
```

My script, which has worked fine for hours 0-23, is the following:

```
def my_import(f):
df_time = pd.read_csv(f, skiprows=8, usecols=[0,1,2,3])
df_time = df_time.astype(int)
df_time.columns = ['Year','Month','Day','Hour']
df_time['period'] = df_time.apply(lambda x : str(int(x['Year']))
+str(int(x['Month'])).zfill(2)
+str(int(x['Day'])).zfill(2)
+' '+str(int(x['Hour'])/100).zfill(2), axis = 1)
df_time.loc[:, 'Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_time['period'], format = '%Y/%m/%d %H')
df_time.drop(['Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Hour', 'period'], axis = 1, inplace = True)
df_DBT = pd.read_csv(f, skiprows=8, usecols=[6])
df = pd.concat([df_time,df_DBT], axis = 1)
df = df.set_index(['Date'])
return df
```

The problem arises with the 24, which pandas does not recognise. I can easily replace 24 with 0, but the challenge is increasing one day.

If I add +1 to the column value before datetime parsing, then every 31st day become 32nd - generating further errors.
I have tried amending the script to impose the `to_datetime` command to date and time separately, but without luck.

This is very frustrating!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please don't underestimate Pandas power!

Demo (using Pandas 0.19.0):

Data:

```
In [33]: df
Out[33]:
    Year  Month  Day  Hour  Val
0   2030      1    1     1  2.4
1   2030      1    1     2  2.1
2   2030      1    1     3  1.7
3   2030      1    1     4  1.0
4   2030      1    1     5  0.9
5   2030      1    1     6  1.5
6   2030      1    1     7  1.1
7   2030      1    1     8  0.6
8   2030      1    1     9  1.4
9   2030      1    1    10  2.2
10  2030      1    1    11  2.0
11  2030      1    1    12  3.0
12  2030      1    1    13  2.4
13  2030      1    1    14  2.6
14  2030      1    1    15  3.1
15  2030      1    1    16  2.6
16  2030      1    1    17  1.9
17  2030      1    1    18  1.9
18  2030      1    1    19  2.6
19  2030      1    1    20  1.7
20  2030      1    1    21  1.1
21  2030      1    1    22  1.3
22  2030      1    1    23  1.4
23  2030      1    1    24  1.7    # <-----------
24  2030      1    2     1  2.1
```

Solution:

```
In [34]: pd.to_datetime(df[['Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Hour']])
Out[34]:
0    2030-01-01 01:00:00
1    2030-01-01 02:00:00
2    2030-01-01 03:00:00
3    2030-01-01 04:00:00
4    2030-01-01 05:00:00
5    2030-01-01 06:00:00
6    2030-01-01 07:00:00
7    2030-01-01 08:00:00
8    2030-01-01 09:00:00
9    2030-01-01 10:00:00
10   2030-01-01 11:00:00
11   2030-01-01 12:00:00
12   2030-01-01 13:00:00
13   2030-01-01 14:00:00
14   2030-01-01 15:00:00
15   2030-01-01 16:00:00
16   2030-01-01 17:00:00
17   2030-01-01 18:00:00
18   2030-01-01 19:00:00
19   2030-01-01 20:00:00
20   2030-01-01 21:00:00
21   2030-01-01 22:00:00
22   2030-01-01 23:00:00
23   2030-01-02 00:00:00    # <-----------
24   2030-01-02 01:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this prior to datetime parsing code:

```
df_time['Day'] = np.where(df_time.Hour == 24, df_time.Day+1, df_time.Day)
df_time['Hour'] = np.where(df_time.Hour == 24, 0, df_time.Hour)

df_time['Month'] = np.where((df_time.Day > 31) & (df_time.Month.isin([1, 3, 5, 7,8, 10, 12])), df_time.Month+1, df_time.Month)
df_time['Day'] = np.where((df_time.Day > 31) & (df_time.Month.isin([1, 3, 5, 7,8, 10, 12])), 1, df_time.Day)

df_time['Month'] = np.where((df_time.Day > 30) & (df_time.Month.isin([4, 6, 9, 11])), df_time.Month+1, df_time.Month)
df_time['Day'] = np.where((df_time.Day > 30) & (df_time.Month.isin([4, 6, 9, 11])), 1, df_time.Day)

df_time['Month'] = np.where((df_time.Day > 28) & (df_time.Month == 2)), df_time.Month+1, df_time.Month)
df_time['Day'] = np.where((df_time.Day > 28) & (df_time.Month == 2)), 1, df_time.Day)

df_time['Year'] = np.where(df_time.Month > 12, df_time.Year+1, df_time.Year)
df_time['Month'] = np.where(df_time.Year> 12, 1, df_time.Month)
```